# returning collections using linking tables and JPA

Tags: jpa, linker

After struggling for days attempting to get back collections that are linked to a table via a foreign key, I just realized that the tables I am linking to are actually LINKING tables to other tables with the actual data (chock one up for normalized tables).

I am still struggling to get collections out of ManyToOne annotated variables with references to foreign keys, but is there a way I can pull the data back from the table that actually contains the information?  Has anyone run into an instance of this?

UPDATE: AS per request I will be posting some code instances...  This would be my named query in the entity that I will be calling...

```
@NamedQuery(name="getQuickLaunchWithCollections", query = "SELECT q FROM QuickLaunch q LEFT JOIN FETCH q.quickLaunchDistlistCollection LEFT JOIN FETCH q.quickLaunchPermCollection LEFT JOIN FETCH q.quickLaunchProviderCollection")})
```

These would be the collections that I am looking to fill...

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="quickLaunchId", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<QuickLaunchPerm> quickLaunchPermCollection;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="quickLaunchId", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<QuickLaunchProvider> quickLaunchProviderCollection;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="quickLaunchId", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<QuickLaunchDistlist> quickLaunchDistlistCollection;
```

As you can see, I have the fetch type set to eager.  So technically, I should be getting some data back?  But in actuality those are just linking tables the data that I actually want to pull back.  I will need to figure out how to get that data back eventually.

This is how I am calling that named query...

```
listQL = emf.createNamedQuery("getQuickLaunchWithCollections").getResultList();
```

Alright, it appears as though     LEFT JOIN FETCH
is causing my runtime to throw an expception of some kind.  It is pretty unclear as to what it is.  But I feel as though I am getting no where with that technique.  I am going to try something slightly different.

Comment: Doesn't sound to difficult. But post your entities and the code that fails to do what you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest simplifying example, to face the problem, since you are going worldwide now.

Specifying `mappedBy="quickLaunchId"` attribute, you are saying, that `QuickLaunchPerm` entity has `QuickLaunch` as its property named `"quickLaunchId"`. Is this true?

If it is not, then you need to define it in `QuickLaunchPerm`:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "QUICK_LAUNCH_ID")
private QuickLaunch quickLaunchId;

//getters setters
```

Comment: If the answer is correct, you can accept is a correct answer :) Happy2help.